# Windows file path length restriction while migrating users from Mac to Windows

Tags: windows, migration

We are in the process of migrating users from OSX to Windows 10. On Mac, users never had restrictions with theirs paths lengths, so over time, they created many files/directories structures that exceeds the maximum authorized on Windows.

For the future, users will have to deal with this (stupid) restriction that Windows is still imposing in 2017. But the big issues for the moment is when I have to move their data from the old Mac to the new PC. I get errors when Windows finds a file with a too long file path.

I enabled the GPO policy *enable win32 long paths*, but this doesn't help. I think Microsoft fixed the Windows API, but not theirs apps like Windows Explorer.

I found the [TLPD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tlpd/) utility. It scan a file tree and reports files that exceeds the maximum allowed length. Then the user have to rename or trash theirs files. Very time consuming!

I also found [Long Path Fixer](http://corz.org/windows/software/accessories/Long-Path-Fixer-for-Windows.php) utility. This is supposed to allow to copy files with a too long path length, but I failed to use it. It's slow and at the end it just crash.

Do you have better solutions?

Comment: It's a little unclear where data is moving to. Is this data just local to each machine, and is it being moved to a file server or just to the windows workstation? That's pretty wild if people are creating long paths in their Home dir.

Comment: I first copy user's data from the Mac to an USB external hard drive (exfat formatted). Then I copy the data from the external disk to the PC. The problem occurs when I try to copy data from external to PC. Windows complaints.

Comment: So the external is attached to the windows machine, and you're initiating that copy from the Windows host? What kind of copy utility are you using? A program or just copy/paste?

Comment: Yes. I use the Windows Explorer and drag&drop to copy from external hdd to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using robocopy to transfer, it's generally pretty good at getting around that limitation. Look through when you're done though to see if it auto truncated any names.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx

You will also want to verify that Explorer and apps are able to reach those longer file lengths okay before nuking it on the mac.

**Edit:** As far as accessing those files once they're copied... that's the Windows API limitation kicking in. If they're relatively uncommon, you can use extended-length prefix or substitute to jump into those paths...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx

If they're common enough that manual workarounds are a pain, then I would suggest trying the /FAT parameter on the Robocopy job. I've never used it, but it appears to use the 8.3 naming scheme which might auto-truncate those paths for you; not sure if this would cause other issues though. Another option is if these machines are Windows 10, you can enable a registry key to get around the limitation in Explorer (see above MSDN article).

Comment: robocopy succeed to copy all the files. A good step done! But the stupid Windows Explorer still unable to open the files.

Comment: Edited my answer to address that piece, check it out and let me know if one of those options work for you.

Comment: Yeah, we are running Windows 10 Anniversary Update. I already activated the GPO setting that's supposed to disable the path length restriction. I verified and LongPathsEnabled is set to 1 in the registry. I'm going into vacation, I'll check this again at my return. Thanks!